# Why firefox show "this page uses weak connection" connection not secure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, debian, proxy

OS : Kali Linux 2020.3
DE : KDE

Problem:
I have used a paid proxy with username/password with https://github.com/himanshub16/ProxyMan as a proxy configuring tool.

So the proxy works fine and all is good, after a while I have noticed that firefox does not save any passwords and show the message as image bellow:

[image]

So I reset the proxy and did not use it any more, but the problem is still there.
I also use chromium, no problem with it.

kindly, could any one tell me what is the problem ? and how to fix it ?

Thanks for all

Comment: What's the full URL you are connecting to? Your browser seems to hide it - some browsers will hide unless you click in there, then show it. Does it start `http://` or `https://` `s` is secure, plain old `http` isn't. Most browsers these days will default to https unless specified otherwise.

Comment: all links even google.com !!

Comment: all links does not matter if it use SSL/TLS or not.

Comment: It says weak encryption so it’s using encryption, and if you open the developer toolbar, and look at the Security tab, it should ID the specific cipher and/or protocol it doesn’t deem safe enough by modern standards.